# Post Data into API From flutter

Tags: flutter

I have an API,which is written in `Node.js` .It is used for logging purpose.Now i'm using the same from a flutter application for performing the same Operation.

```
 API  :  http://192.168.137.1:5050/User/Login
```

How post data to the API from flutter application

```
Expected Input :
 { Data: { USER_NAME: 'usenmae', PASSWORD: 'password' } }
```

1.From Flutter

```
static Future<String> loginPost(String email, String password) async {
    Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap = {
      'Data': {'USER_NAME': email,'PASSWORD' : password}
    };
    try {
      final response = await http.post(
         'http://192.168.137.1:5050/User/Login',
        body: jsonMap,
      );
      return response.body;

    } catch (exception) {

    }
    return null;
  }
```

After calling the API by using the above code snippets i got some errors

```
Error : I/flutter ( 4149): send message exception called
I/flutter ( 4149): type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, String>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast
```

I want pass the username and password through the api by  wrapping the same with an another Data object,which look likes   `{ Data: { USER_NAME: 'usenmae', PASSWORD: 'password' } }`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to encoded as json as said before and also put this in your header 'Content-type': 'application/json'

Answer (score 1):

Before passing data to http.post(), encode the jsonMap data using dart:convert.

```
import 'dart:convert' as convert;

  final response = await http.post(
    'http://192.168.137.1:5050/User/Login',
    body: convert.jsonEncode(jsonMap),
    headers: {"Content-type" : "application/json"}
  );
```

Comment: Tried passing data to API by encoding with `jsonEncode`.But passed data such as username and password not getting on the API.It return null while printing `req.body` on the API side in `Node js`.

`console.log(req.body);` return null